# PHP Mac: fopen fails to open strea: no such file or directory and others

Tags: php, html

I have registration.php in my data folder which is in the source folder so that isn't the issue. What I'm doing is recording my website's form data `$dataRecord` and trying to save it in this csv file that I have.

But I'm getting four errors:

> Warning: fopen(data/registration.csv): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /users/s/j/sjflanag/www-root/cs008/lab11/form.php
>   on line 225
>
> Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in /users/s/j/sjflanag/www-root/cs008/lab11/form.php on line 228
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /users/s/j/sjflanag/www-root/cs008/lab11/form.php on line 231
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sendMail() in
>   /users/s/j/sjflanag/www-root/cs008/lab11/form.php on line 273

```
$myFolder = 'data/';

$myFileName = 'registration';

$fileExt = '.csv';

$filename = $myFolder . $myFileName . $fileExt;
if ($debug) {
    print PHP_EOL . '<p>filename is ' . $filename;
}

$file = fopen($filename, 'a');

fputcsv($file, $dataRecord);

fclose($file);
```

Comment: errors seem clear

Comment: Errors 2 and 3 are merely caused by the first error.  You might use the magic constant \_\_DIR\_\_ as the first part of $myFolder and get that fixed.

The "Fatal Error" is caused by code you didn't post.  Note that the native PHP function is mail().